# Use sqlite3 in Electron with Ionic 4

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, electron, ionic4

I would like to use Electron for Desktop in my Ionic 4 application. But I can't get it work with cordova-sqlite-storage plugin. It seems like Ionic is now recommending Electron for Ionic Desktop, but some cordova plugins don't work.

I used to code with sql.js but it doesn't support foreign keys cascade delete and transaction/commit/rollback

Is there a workaround to use cordova-sqlite-plugin with electron, or another way to use sqlite3 with Electron and a Ionic 4 application ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to use those libraries you mention in Cordova or Electron. Their implementation were made to work for mobile OS'es (cordova-sqlite-plugin) and NodeJS API (sqlite3). You said that you were using ionic4 so what you could do is used the Platform property ***is*** method to check if it's a Desktop or Mobile and act accordingly.